# How should I do software profiling?

Tags: java, swing, profiling, jprofiler

I'm doing an assignment on software profiling, but I can't seem to get anywhere. I'm using JProfiler.

When I start profiling it, the CPU time returns "java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run" as the one that consume the most CPU time and the main cause seems to be javax.swing.JFileChooser's constructor and run() method based on the call tree. I tried overriding JFileChooser's methods but it won't show any progress.

I tried running a few operations in it and it's still the same.

Can anyone give any advice on how I should do profiling, am I missing or misunderstanding something, or what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define suitable filters to see your own classes. Open the session settings, go to the "Filter Settings" section and delete the default excludes. Then, add inclusive filters for the top level packages of your own code, say "com.mycorp.myproject.".

If your code is in the default package, move it to a package first.